# Usage mongo aggregate and project

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have one collection similar this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("57dc2b63add5c5e91f185fe0"),
"level" : 2,
"profili" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439011"),
        "idprofilo" : ObjectId("57fe3c51569b5c0afb88498b"),
        "costopag" : 1,
        "pagmax" : 10,
        "pagmin" : 1
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("507f191e810c19729de860ea"),
        "idprofilo" : ObjectId("57fe3c51569b5c0afb88498b"),
        "costopag" : 0.5,
        "pagmax" : 100,
        "pagmin" : 11
    }
],
"__v" : 0
},
{
"_id" : ObjectId("57dc39945aec26b303053dd7"),
"level" : 2,
"profili" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439012"),
        "idprofilo" : ObjectId("57fe3c51569b5c0afb88498b"),
        "costopag" : 10,
        "pagmax" : 100,
        "pagmin" : 11
    }
]
},
{
"_id" : ObjectId("57e7ff05a0ef6d07c3048d7f"),
"level" : 2,
"profili" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439013"),
        "idprofilo" : ObjectId("57fe3c51569b5c0afb88498c"),
        "costopag" : 0.5,
        "pagmax" : 10,
        "pagmin" : 1
    }
]
},
{
"_id" : ObjectId("57e7ff54a0ef6d07c3048d81"),
"level" : 2,
"profili" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439014"),
        "idprofilo" : ObjectId("57fe3c51569b5c0afb88498c"),
        "costopag" : 5,
        "pagmax" : 10,
        "pagmin" : 1
    }
],
"__v" : 0
}
```

I need to search one docs that have a specific "profili".
If I execute this find:

```
database.Utente.find({
      "level":2,
      profili: {
        $elemMatch:{
          idprofilo: '57fe3c51569b5c0afb88498b',
          pagmin: {$lte:2},
          pagmax: {$gte:2}
        }
      }
    })
```

The results is:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("57dc2b63add5c5e91f185fe0"),
"level" : 2,
"profili" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439011"),
        "idprofilo" : ObjectId("57fe3c51569b5c0afb88498b"),
        "costopag" : 1,
        "pagmax" : 10,
        "pagmin" : 1
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("507f191e810c19729de860ea"),
        "idprofilo" : ObjectId("57fe3c51569b5c0afb88498b"),
        "costopag" : 0.5,
        "pagmax" : 100,
        "pagmin" : 11
    }
],
"__v" : 0
}
```

If is possible, I would not the profili.id=507f191e810c19729de860ea because doesn't responde at request.
I have read that is it possible with .aggregate and $project operator, but I don't understand how I can.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `aggregate` with [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) at the `$project` stage:

```
db.test.aggregate([
  {
      $match: {
          level: 2
      }
  },
  {
      $project: {
          level: 1,
          profili: {
              $filter: {
                  input: '$profili',
                  as: 'prof',
                  cond: {
                      $and : [
                          {$eq: ['$$prof.idprofilo', ObjectId('57fe3c51569b5c0afb88498b')]},
                          {$lte: ['$$prof.pagmin', 2]},
                          {$gte: ['$$prof.pagmax', 2]}
                      ]
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
])
```

If you would like to remove all the documents with empty `profili` just add another `$match` stage:

```
{
    $match: {
        profili: { $nin: [[], null] }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @TomG, the code works but why the search is made also for other level? The first `level: 1` is not a filter? If I see only the results of `level: 1` I add a `$match` with `level: 1`.  And where I filter empty `profili` and null `profili`. If I add operator `$or` at `$match` doesn't work. Thanks a lot for help

Comment: @Francesco Sorry I didn't see you wanted to filter `level:2` I added it to the first `$match`. Also for the second `$match` I changed that it will filter out empty and null `profili`